# I continously get this error Internal Server Error

Tags: python, flask

**Heres my html file**
**login.html**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="content-section">
    <form method="POST" action= "">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Join Today</legend>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{form.username.label(class="form=control-label") }}
                {{form.username.label(class="form=control form-control-lg") }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{form.email.label(class="form=control-label") }}
                {{form.email.label(class="form=control form-control-lg") }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{form.password.label(class="form=control-label") }}
                {{form.password.label(class="form=control form-control-lg") }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{form.confirm_password.label(class="form=control-label") }}
                {{form.confirm_password.label(class="form=control form-control-lg") }}
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div calss="form-group">
            {{ form.submit(class="btn-outline-info" )}}
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="border-top pt-3"> 
    <small class="text-muted">
Already have an account? <a class="ml-2" href="{{ url_for('login') }}"> sign Up

</a>
    </small>
</div>
{% endblock content}
```

**Heres my flask file**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request
from forms import registrationForm, loginForm
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET _KEY'] = 'here'

@app.route("/login")
def login():
    form = loginForm()
    return render_template('login.html', title='Login', form=form)
```

**When I run the flask app it gives me a error at http://127.0.0.1:5000/login saying that " The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application."** I'm trying to createa flask web form pls help

Comment: Is there supposed to be a space in `SECRET _KEY`?

Comment: Also a missing % in your html: `{% endblock content}`

Comment: The server should produce a traceback in the console. Can you show what that is. It will point to the issue.